# How to modify the name of the class (variable instead of hardcoded) in Intent?

Tags: java, android, string, class, android-intent

```
final Button voteYes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.voteYes);

    voteYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent successPhase = new Intent(player1.this, player5.class);
                startActivity(successPhase);

        }
    });
```

I have a integer variable that ranges from 1 to 5, says int number. So, my question is, instead of fixed "player5.class", if I want it to be player[number].class , what can I do? (Instead of hardcoded "5", I want it to be "number")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can do something like following for example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
String myClassName = "player" + number; // use full package of class 
intent.setClassName(context, myClassname;
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Intent inGame = new Intent();
String leader = "player3";
inGame.setClassName(MainActivity.this, leader);
startActivity(inGame); When I click at the button, the app crashes, while the above works just fine.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to use full package of class. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
Class players [] = {Player1.class, Player2.class,Player3.class, Player4.class,Player5.class};
```

use like this:

```
Intent successPhase = new Intent(this, players[number]);
                startActivity(successPhase);
```